# How can I link a static lib generated by DCC32 with the option -JL in C++builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, .lib

I'm trying to use a static library in my C++ Builder project. The lib is created by using DCC32 to compile Delphi source code with -JL option. My Delphi source code is design as a "Designtime and runtime" package, which mean s all the code is built into one package. I want to know how can I use this static library in our C++ Builder project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a static library. It is the import library for a Delphi package (BPL file).

Comment: In fact, the 32 bit Delphi compiler `dcc32` cannot create static lib files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David said, the **Delphi compiler can't create static lib files at all**. What you are trying to link to is an **import library** for a designtime/runtime package.

Delphi (and C++Builder) packages are not static libs, they are DLLs with a lot of extra information onboard, which makes it easy for Delphi and C++Builder code to link to them and the types inside. They are more or less equivalent to C# assemblies (guess where the C# people got the idea ;-).

To use such a package, in case you really *want* to use them, select the "build with packages" option from the project options and select this package too.

But if you want to create a single, standalone application, you don't build with packages and the Pascal files get linked into your application **as if they came from a static library**. But instead of specifying one lib file, you simply specify the *.pas* files in the project manager, i.e. you simply add the bunch of *.pas* (or *.obj*) files to your application directly.

The project will take care of compiling the Pascal files and linking them to your application.

Note that to install **components** into the IDE, you need a design time package (and that might link to a runtime package). But you don't need packages for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any way to create a single, standalone application with the output of DCC32 (BPL, BPI, LIB)? *.pas or *.obj is not available for me.

Comment: You could use the LIB file to link to the BPL. But note that BPLs are very version-specific, so a BPL generated with one version cannot be used by an application created with another version. That is why I generally suffix the BPLs with the compiler version (without dot), e.g. for Rio, I use the suffix 260, as in myNewPackage260.bpl

Answer (score 0):

These are some steps for your consideration:

1. Use -JP to generate obj files
2. Add these obj files in link step into your ilink32 command

If you use IDE and do not which ilink32 params then you may consider procexp or procmon to see these params.